# Batch: Array index returns blank

Tags: arrays, batch-file, for-loop

In this piece of code I'm trying to make a list fit the screen in WinPE by alternating into two columns. But when I put `!modelsvar[%increment%]:~20!` in the echo it returns only ~20. Strange because `!modelsvar[%%D]:~20!` works fine. I've tried many variations of ! and % but no luck. Anyone know if there's is a specific rule that I'm missing?

I have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` enabled

```
set modelsx=%counter%
set /a counter=0

for /l %%D in (1,2,%modelsx%) do (
set /a counter+=1
set /a increment=!counter!+1
ECHO !counter!. !modelsvar[%%D]:~20!      !increment!. !modelsvar[%increment%]:~20!
set /a counter+=1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /l %%D in (1,2,%modelsx%) do (
   set /a counter+=1
   set /a increment=counter+1
   for %%X in (!increment!) do (
      ECHO !counter!. !modelsvar[%%D]:~20!      !increment!. !modelsvar[%%X]:~20!
   )
   set /a counter+=1
)
```

Further details at [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: That works. Thank you. I suspected it had something to do with process order but i didn't think i could echo from two for loops in one line alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

You're expanding `increment` immediately within `ECHO`, that is like `%increment%`, so the returned value is the one *before* the for loop executes.

Here is another work-around:

```
set modelsx=%counter%
set /a counter=0

for /l %%D in (1,2,%modelsx%) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    set /a increment=!counter!+1
    call ECHO !counter!. !modelsvar[%%D]:~20!      !increment!. %%modelsvar[!increment!]:~20%%
    set /a counter+=1
)
```